# pandas fill missing cells with similar group data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill missing data with data found in other fields, for example, I have a table:

```
Brand   Model   Make
Toyota  Corolla Japan
Toyota  Crescida    Japan
Toyota  Land Cruiser    
Ford    Escape  America
Ford    Explorer    America
Ford    Edge    
Ford    Focus
```

I know from other rows that Toyota is from Japan and Ford from America. How can I do this in Pandas to give me the below?

```
Brand   Model   Make
Toyota  Corolla Japan
Toyota  Crescida    Japan
Toyota  Land Cruiser    Japan
Ford    Escape  America
Ford    Explorer    America
Ford    Edge    America
Ford    Focus   America
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `df['Make'] = df.groupby('Brand')['Make'].fillna(method='ffill')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df=df1[['Brand','Make']].groupby(['Brand']).agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()` to get the common occurences for the make column on the basis of Brand.
After that you can use the following code

```
for index,value in enumerate(df1['Make']):
    if value==None:
        brand=df1['Brand'][index]
        df1['Make'][index]=df['Make'][df['Brand']==brand].to_list()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it in two steps:

1. created another df:
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Brand')['Make'].first())
2. lookup up Make from df2 to fill original df:
   df['Make']=df.Brand.apply(lambda x: df2[df2['Brand']==x]['Make'])

   Brand     Model   Make
   0  Toyota   Corolla  Japan
   1  Toyota  Crescida  Japan
   2  Toyota     Prado  Japan